# Get number of files in git repository at any revision

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to find the number of files in a Git repository at a given revision, preferably without having to check out the revision first.

I thought `git ls-files` might get me somewhere, but I'm not able to see any way of passing Git a revision for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls-files` operates on the index, which is by nature associated with the current checkout. Use [`ls-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html), as in `git ls-tree -r --name-only <tree-ish>`. If you just want to count lines, using `--name-only` will speed things up by limiting the output.

Comment: Wouldn't this list all things in the `treeish` rather than just the files?

Comment: @Noufal It only lists the blobs, not any of the tree objects.

Comment: I used this command: `git ls-tree -r --name-only <sha>`, an example being `git ls-tree -r --name-only 2e6afb2ee0583fba72d76f49d8e04a10b734f7a7`. I am hoping that's what you mean by `<tree-ish>`. It certainly seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, when you see `<tree-ish>` in the manual you can use a commit, a ref, or a tree.

Comment: Ah. The `-r` actually goes recursively and "expands" each tree in the treeish to the blobs it holds. Nice answer. +1.

Comment: you could actually run that command through wc -l and get an idea of how many files & directories there are. `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | wc -l`